# Command line Doctrine ORM with Silex: You are missing a "cli-config.php" or "config/cli-config.php" file in your project

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, silex

I am trying to use Doctrine ORM with Silex, and finding it an altogether frustrating experience, due to the lack of consistent documentation.

When I run `vendor/bin/doctrine` at the console, I get the following output:

**output:**

```
You are missing a "cli-config.php" or "config/cli-config.php" file in your
project, which is required to get the Doctrine Console working. You can use the
following sample as a template:

<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner;

// replace with file to your own project bootstrap
require_once 'bootstrap.php';

// replace with mechanism to retrieve EntityManager in your app
$entityManager = GetEntityManager();

return ConsoleRunner::createHelperSet($entityManager);
```

This is my composer.json file:

```
{
    "require": { 
        "silex/silex": "2.0.*@dev",
        "symfony/yaml": "2.6.7",
        "doctrine/dbal": "~2.2",
        "dflydev/doctrine-orm-service-provider": "2.0.*@dev",
        "khepin/yaml-fixtures-bundle": "~0.8.1"
    },
    "config": {
            "bin-dir": "bin"
    }
}
```

This is the php code that registers the Doctrine service etc.

```
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache;
use Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache;
use Silex\Provider\DoctrineServiceProvider;
use Dflydev\Provider\DoctrineOrm\DoctrineOrmServiceProvider;

$app->register(new DoctrineServiceProvider(), array(
                'db.options' => array(// http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/doctrine.html
                    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql', 
                    'dbname' => 'foobar',
                    'host' => 'localhost',
                    'user' => 'root',
                    'password' => 'root',
                    'charset' => 'utf8'
                )
            ));

$app->register(new DoctrineORMServiceProvider(), 
                array(
                        'db.orm.proxies_dir'  => __DIR__.'/../cache/doctrine/proxy',
                        'db.orm.proxies_namespace'  => 'DoctrineProxy',
                        'db.orm.cache'  =>  !$app['debug'] &&extension_loaded('apc') ? new ApcCache() : new ArrayCache(),
                        'db.orm.auto_generate_proxies' => true,
                        'db.orm.entities' => array(array(
                                                        'type' => 'simple_yaml', 
                                                        'path' => __DIR__.'/src/Resources/config/doctrine',
                                                        'namespace' => 'Foobar\Entity',
                                                        )),
                ));
```

This is my configuration file (bin/cli-config.php)

```
<?php

// retrieve EntityManager
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner;

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/src/app.php';

$isDevMode = $app['debug'];

$paths = $app['db.orm.entities']['path'];
$config = Setup::createYAMLMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($app['db.options'], $config);

return ConsoleRunner::createHelperSet($entityManager);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: move `bin/cli-config.php` in  `config/cli-config.php`

Comment: @Leggendario: It would have been nice if this had been docuented somewhere (or did I miss it)? As it turns out, this seems to be the answer, so submit it as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to move `bin/cli-config.php` in `config/cli-config.php`.

Unfortunately I have not found documentation about it. I opened `doctrine/dbal/bin/doctrine-dbal.php` and checked how it worked.

Comment: what to do if i dont have `cli-config.php` file in bin folder?

Answer (score 0):

Both **cli-config.php** and **bootstrap.php** should be placed in **same folder**. They are working for me if either I place them at root of my zend project or in root->config folder.

Then orm:convert-mapping command in terminal on mac runs successfully.

```
./vendor/bin/doctrine orm:convert-mapping --namespace="Quiz\Model\Entity" --force  --from-database annotation ./module/Quiz/src/Model/
```